# How to add the class in placeholder?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

Modifing some changes in ui-grid.js as per my requirement.
Tried adding unicode on placeholder.It's working fine.
But, I need a common(B/W) search icon instead of blue framed search icon.
Facing issue whiling tring to add the class in placeholder.
in code:
[image]

After adding the class in placeholder.

[image]

Am i doing anything wrong,while adding the class ? Help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add html in `placeholder` attribute rather I'd recommend you to add `class` on your input element using `ng-class` when you need icon.

```
<input ng-attr-placeholder="{{colFilter.placeholder}}" ng-class="{search: colFilter.placeholder}"
```

**CSS**

```
input.search {
    padding-left:20px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position-y: 1px;
    background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAASCAYAAABb0P4QAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAADbSURBVDhP5ZI9C4MwEIb7//+BEDgICA6C4OQgBJy6dRIEB6EgCNkEJ4e3iT2oHzH9wHbpAwfyJvfkJDnhYH4kHDVKlSAigSAQoCiBKjVGXvaxFXZnxBQYkSlBICII+22K4jM63rbHSthCSdsskVX9Y6KxR5XJSSpVy6GbpbBKp6aw0BzM0ShCe1iKihMXC6EuQtMQwukzPFu3fFd4+C+/cimUNxy6WQkNnmdzL3NYPfDmLVuhZf2wZYz80qDkKX1St3CXAfVMqq4cz3hTaGEpmctxDPmB0M/fCYEbAwZYyVKYcroAAAAASUVORK5CYII=);
}
```

Comment: @KishorVelayutham Glad to know, Thanks :)